# Introducción manual consulta SQL en Power BI

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

Pertenezco a un grupo de empresas que utilizan el mismo ERP con una base de datos Oracle común que tiene unas 100.000 vistas y estoy intentando cargar en Power BI la base de datos del ERP de todo el grupo.

Quiero explotar un informe con 3 ó 4 vistas de esa base de datos pero cuando Power BI está cargando las vistas solo me muestra las 10.000 primeras y no sé puedo acceder a las vistas de 10.001 en adelante.

La dificultad está en que la empresa usa solo una parte de estas vistas y no existe una distribución de las vistas por empresa sino que están distribuidas irregularmente en el listado alfabético de vistas por lo que las que necesito no aparecen listadas y no las puedo seleccionar.

Conozco el nombre de las vistas y podría introducir manualmente el nombre pero no sé donde podría hacerlo.

Al seguir las instrucciones del comentario de Roger Torné y seleccionar cualquier tabla de la lista y transformar datos, dar clic en origen, efectivamente tiene acceso a todas las tablas pero no permite la búsqueda y esta vez está limitado a 1.000 registros, hacer scrolling en una tabla de este tamaño se hace eterno. ¿Alguna sugerencia para acceder de una forma más natural?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A ver si alguien puede ayudar. Agradecido de antemano.

Comment: Ciertamente me parece una demanda algo surrealista. ¿Qué vas a hacer con 10.000 objetos en Power BI? Son tablas que deberás relacionar manualmente con otras tablas. Puede que el enfoque no sea el correcto. ¿Son tablas idénticas? ¿No puedes agruparlas en un UNION ALL?

Comment: Hola Roger:

Gracias por tu aportación.
Es mi primera consulta aquí e igual no he contextualizado adecuadamente la situación. Añado información:
Pertenezco a un grupo de empresas que utilizan el mismo ERP con una base de datos común y lo que estoy intentando cargar es la base de datos del ERP de todo el grupo.
En cada informe no voy a usar más de 3 ó 4 vistas, pero mi empresa usa solo una parte de estas vistas y no existe una distribución de las vistas por empresa sino que están distribuidas irregularmente en el listado alfabético de vistas.
¿alguna idea de como proceder?

Comment: Prueba con esto, selecciona cualquier tabla de la lista, no importa. Ir a transformar datos, selecciona la tabla en el lado izquierdo y en el lado derecho, haz clic en el paso de origen, enumerará cada tabla de la base de datos, aquí puedes filtrar por la tabla que estás buscando y seleccionar la tabla

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. De esta forma todas las vistas son teoricamente accesibles pero  en la práctica es bastante complicado acceder a las vistas necesarias. Edito la entrada para añadir la imagen de como se visualiza. A ver si alguien puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por un lado se me ocurre que, como conoces el nombre de las vistas que tienes que utilizar, podrías seleccionar directamente la vista en las opciones avanzadas:

[image: Oracle Database - Opciones avanzadas - Introducir SQL]

De esta forma puedes introducir el SELECT de tus vistas directamente sin tener problemas al seleccionarlas en el desplegable.

Por otro lado, si sigues el camino que has tomado hasta ahora, podrías seleccionar siempre la primera vista (creo que se llama "ACURE") y cuando haya cargado esta vista editas el paso de Power Query en el que aparece ese nombre y lo sustituyes por la vista que quieras traer en su lugar en la barra de fórmulas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.